# For Loop, Sleep, Page Not Loading due to Loop

Tags: php, loops, post, for-loop, freeze

I am creating a small Bitcoin payment gateway to pay 0.25 BTC and only need 1 confirmation. I have created a form (form.html) which shows a unique random address (`$_POST['address']`) so on the next page after you hit submit I need it to display a page and do some checks for me... but when I hit submit it just says "waiting for page to load" at the bottom of my browser and doesn't actually load the page up (which has HTML on it), I'm sure this is because of a for loop hogging the page but I'm not sure how to get around it.

My for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 900; $i++) {

    $conf = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/' . $_POST['address'] . '?confirmations=1');
    $seen = file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/q/addressfirstseen/' . $_POST['address']);

        if ($seen != 0) {
            if($conf >= 25000000) {
                echo "Payment Complete <br><br>";
                break;
            } elseif ($conf != 0 && $conf < 25000000) {
                echo "You Did Not Pay Enough Bitcoins<br><br>";
                break;
            }
        }
        sleep(30);
}
```

I'm pretty rusty with PHP and this is my first attempt in a while, if anyone could point me in the right direction to what I am doing incorrect that would be much appreciated.

Thank you for any time anyone spends on this.

Comment: Well you're using PHP .. Although this could be possible via `flush`, I'd rather switch to JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define **i** as a loop counter but you are not using it?!
most probably none of the break criteria is fulfilled and you are actually doing a big sleep 900 * 30 sec = 450 minutes
I'm absolutely sure that you don't need this.
not to mention that you have to change some vars in cnf, ini ... if you need a response after that long time

from what I can see, $seen is probably zero by default and/or $conf is < = 0

[sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

for delay in milliseconds, use
[usleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

haven't used php for some years, but I believe sleep is in sec.
try not doing front-end checks with back-end language as the first comment under your post says but I can only guess what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: Doh, Sleep was only meant to be 1 second, so 15 minutes (usual length of one confirmation, page still doesn't load though) and you are correct, im not using the loop counter. Would there be a better way to check all of this information over and over?